# Using Google Sheets to bulk collect the number of Google Search results for given keywords

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml, regex, importhtml

I would like to create a Google Sheets that will allow me to paste in a list of 25 or so keywords in column A and would then return the number of search results for each of those terms in column B.

Is that something that is possible?

Any suggestions?

<sub>I haven't been able to find much online.</sub>

Comment: You probably can't do that with just Google Sheets. The solutions I've seen for getting that number involve either using the Google Search AJAX API or doing screen scraping, neither of which are practical to implement in Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

[Borrowing a formula that's been tried before](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/XXcPFSf3W2c), I was able to see results but it doesn't work consistently.

[image]

The first few times, the formula threw the error: Could not fetch URL: http://www.google.com/search?q=al jaffee

[Going by the experience of others who have reported this issue on various forums](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45047047/325251), it works once in a while when the sheet is closed & re-opened

Answer (score 0):

here it is - **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q-EsxRwZcPDpQwZqrSQqIBwC9-BD7-MbktVdJBw0KCY/edit#gid=0)**

**cell B1: `=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(MID(INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.google.com/search? 
         q="&A1&"";"table";1);4;2);6;23);"\D+";))`**

[image: 2]